# Python - String List Newline

Tags: python, string, newline

Is there a way to separate list items with `\n` sequence?
here's the code:

```
month_names = [
                ['January', 'February', 'March'],
                ['April', 'May', 'June'],
                ['July', 'August', 'September'],
                ['October', 'November', 'December'],
                ]   
print month_names
```

the problem is when I try to add `\n` or `'\n'` to the list or print like :

```
print month_names + '\n'
```

or

```
['January', 'February', 'March'], '\n',
```

syntax or type error raises and sometime it prints \n.

The Desired Output is :

```
'January', 'February', 'March'
'April', 'May', 'June'
'July', 'August', 'September'
'October', 'November', 'December'
```

and I want to keep it as a list so I can recall the 2nd list like:

```
'April', 'May', 'June'
```

Comment: Why do you want it? What is it that you are trying to achieve? Seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me . Can you show what you are expecting as the output?

Comment: @AnandSKumar Trying to define a list which contains: Spring (Jan, Feb, Mar)
Summer (Apr, May, June)
and so one. and when I recall whole the list it prints whole of it.

Comment: What is your desired/expected output? Please share.

Comment: @closevoters: I see no where OP's aversion in using join.

Comment: @Heartagramir Please update the question with what else you are expecting as output

Comment: @AnandSKumar Updated.

Comment: @Heartagramir you should checkout the answers below I believe they come close to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @AnandSKumar The Problem is solved but I'm trying to explain the question in better way.

Comment: ya, forget about the inner list :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe what you want is a simple concatenation of individual months with new line

```
>>> print '\n'.join(map('\n'.join, month_names))
January
February
March
April
May
June
July
August
September
October
November
December
```

In case, you want quarters in each line, one of the following should work

```
>>> print '\n'.join(map(' '.join, month_names))
January February March
April May June
July August September
October November December

>>> print '\n'.join(map(str, month_names))
['January', 'February', 'March']
['April', 'May', 'June']
['July', 'August', 'September']
['October', 'November', 'December']
```

Comment: print '\n'.join(map('  '.join, month_names)) is what I've expected.

Comment: @Heartagramir If the answer was helpful for you, you should [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (by clicking on the tick mark on the left side) .